# pipe not readable c

Tags: c, pipe

I'm working on some code involving pipes. The idea is that I'm supposed to have a process looping indefinitely and add data to the pipe as it comes (I'm testing this by reading a file, and going line by line in a while loop).

If I set the other process (the one that reads the pipe) to sleep so the entire file is read I have no problems and get all the file in the output. As soon as I remove the sleep (so now the 2 processes start simultaneously with the 2nd process reading the information off the pipe as it comes), my code goes straight to the else block of my code below and I never see any actual output. What am I doing wrong?

```
close(pipe[1]);  
sleep(5);

while (1) {

  nbytes = read(pipe[0], buffer, 200);    

  if(errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {      
    printf("%s", buffer);     
  }

  else {
    printf("I am not blocked here\n");
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. did you make pipe[0] non-blocking?  It'll be something like `int nbio=1; ioctl(pipe[0], FIONBIO, &nbio);`

   you're checking for error wrong.

```
if(nbytes > 0) {
    /* you may need to null-terminate the input buffer prior to display */
    buffer[nbytes] = '\0';
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
else if(errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
    printf("I am not blocked here\n");
    sleep(1);
}
else {
    printf("some other error occurred - if nbytes == 0, then it's EOF.\n");
}
```

probably errno is EWOULDBLOCK the first time through, and then doesn't get updated on successful read, so it looks like EWOULDBLOCK again.

Comment: I'm using ioctl(named_pipeID[0], FIONBIO, NULL); to make the pipe non-blocking. I have tried changing the way I handle the error-checking to the way you suggested, but am still having the exact same issue. Basically, the parent process keeps writing to the pipe and the child keeps going into the error block.

Comment: Yes! problem solved, I just noticed your last two lines. I set the errno = 0 in the error block. I did not realize you have to clear it manually.

Comment: `read` will return -1 on any failure, including EWOULDBLOCK.  It sets `errno` only on failure.  So the appropriate behavior is to check the return value from `read` first, then check `errno` only if `read` indicated failure.  See the man page.  HTH

Comment: You really need to be checking the return value of `read`. Inspecting `errno` alone is highly error-prone.